# Dock Hovering problem in Mac simulator(html)

Tags: html, css, emulation

I am working on an html Mac 11 simulator but when I added the hover effect in the dock it wasn't working properly.
[i was hovering over the icon in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDgFK.jpg)

I was hovering over the icon in the image
this is the CSS code for my dock and icons

```css
.dock {
    height: 75px;
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    border-radius: 24px;
}
.icon {
    width: 75px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    bottom: auto;
}
.icon:hover {
    width: 100px;
}
```

I hope u can help me

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Please provide you HTML code as well.

Comment: this is the code https://codepen.io/FTCCREATOR/pen/jOMgWoG

Comment: We are on version 12 in the mean time

Comment: this is my old question and i have already fixed this issue with some flexbox